# Convertir Fecha de un objeto en Formato ddMMyy

Tags: c#, datetime

tengo una fecha de un que viene de un objeto y es de tipo DATETIME y se necesita que tenga el formato dd/MM/yy

```
DateTime fechaInicialAsoc = DateTime.Parse(objFecha, "ddMMyy");
```

Como puedo convertir sin pasar a realizarlo a string y luego a datetime nuevamente para una consulta en linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objetivo del formato de fecha está restringido a la visualización. Un objeto `DateTime` no tiene un formato como tal, su formato es la representación en `string`.

Si lo que deseas es hacer cálculos o búsquedas entre fechas, lo harás siempre con el objeto `DateTime`, y cuando quieras representarlo le darás el formato que desees, por ejemplo con un `objFecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que intentas no se puede conseguir sin pasarlo a `String` primero, me explico.

Un `DateTime` es simplemente una representación de ticks desde una fecha X

Mientras que a lo que tu llamas formato en este caso `"ddMMyy"` es una representación de string de dichos ticks. A este string si que le puedes aplicar cualquier tipo de formato

¿ Que es un tick?

> Los valores de tiempo se miden en unidades de 100 nanosegundos
>   llamadas ticks, y una fecha particular es el número de ticks desde las
>   12:00 de la medianoche, 1 de enero de 0001 AD (CE) en el calendario
>   GregorianCalendar (excluyendo los ticks que se agregarían por segundos
>   bisiestos) . Por ejemplo, un valor de ticks de 31241376000000000L
>   representa la fecha, viernes 01 de enero, 0100 12:00:00 de la
>   medianoche.